# Bind data from datagrid

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, datagrid, mxml, flash-builder

I have a form that consists of two data grids and a button. Datagrid 1, "myStaticDataGrid", has values I have added for the user to select from. I want the button's click event to send the current selection of myStaticDataGrid to the second datagrid, "myDataGrid". I have been able to accomplish this if I use a text box and a datagrid but I am having trouble finding the right syntax to grab the selection data from myStaticDataGrid.

This is my attempt using the two datagrid approach:

```
<s:Form id="myForm">
//The values from this grid are determined once the button is clicked.
  <s:FormItem id="myDataGrid">
    <s:DataGrid id="bdgFormData">
      <s:typicalItem>
        <s:DataItem formData="Description" xmlData="Value"/>
      </s:typicalItem>
      <s:ArrayCollection id="values"> </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:DataGrid>
  </s:FormItem>


//The values from this grid are determined at runtime.
<s:FormItem id="myStaticDataGrid">
    <s:DataGrid id="userSelects">
        <s:typicalItem>
            <s:DataItem selects="Typical Item" codes="0000"/>
        </s:typicalItem>

        <s:ArrayCollection id="selects">
            <s:DataItem selects="Y" codes="1"/>
            <s:DataItem selects="N" codes="0"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:FormItem>

<s:FormItem label="Add Selects">
    <s:Button label="Go" click="addData(event)"/>
</s:FormItem>
```

My AS event to send the data:

```
protected function addData(event:MouseEvent):void
{

  //Put selected data at the top of the grid.
  items.addItemAt(lstFormData.typicalItem,0)

}
```

My question is where do I bind the grid data?

This is how I send the textbox data to a the datagrid:

```
<s:FormItem label="myDataUtil">
  <s:Label text="Value"/>
  <s:TextInput text="@{lstFormData.typicalItem.formData}"/>
</s:FormItem>
```

Comment: Could you rewrite exactly what you are trying to do. All I understood of what you wrote is you want to bind one grid to the other which seems pointless as you will have 2 grids displaying exactly the same data. In any case this is how you would do it. bdgFormData.dataProvider = bdgFormData.dataProvider

Comment: I have edited the post to describe more of what I am trying to do as well as show what I have done that worked, more or less.

Comment: So let me see if I understand this. You have one datagrid that the datagrid source data will never change. You also have a second datagrid that the dataprovider is based off of the first(static) datagrid with the ability to add more data via TextInput?

Comment: Almost. I mentioned the text input because I was able to put data into the dynamic datagrid, but in the final product I have no need for a text input. The second datagrid starts off empty but will accept more data from the static grid. If staticDataGrid has the values X, Y, and Z the user can click one or all of these values, click the add button and the chosen values will be displayed in dynamicDatGrid. Make sense?

Comment: I found this [example](http://flex4fun.com/2010/11/30/flex4-drag-and-drop-with-data-contains-comparison/). It does exactly what I want to do but it uses drag-drop instead of a click event. That example also uses 2 lists where I am trying to use 2 datagrids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped this up for you unfortunately I only have flex 3 here so you will have to make conversions for whatever you need but you should get the idea of how it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
  <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
  import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
  [Bindable]
  public var originalData:ArrayCollection

  [Bindable]
  public var changingData:ArrayCollection;

  public function init( ):void{
    this.changingData = new ArrayCollection( )
    this.originalData = new ArrayCollection( )
    for( var i:int = 0;i<100;i++){
      var obj:Object = new Object( )
      obj.label = 'slot '+ i;
      obj.value = 's'+i;
      originalData.addItem( obj );
    }
  }

  public function onSelect( e:Event ):void{
    this.changingData.addItem(( e.currentTarget as DataGrid).selectedItem )
  }

  ]]> 
  </mx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid id="myStaticDataGrid" dataProvider="{originalData}"  click="onSelect(event)"/>
<mx:DataGrid id="bdgFormData" dataProvider="{changingData}" x="240" y="0"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Here is an example without binding data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            public function onSelect( e:Event ):void{
                var targetProvider:ArrayCollection = ( bdgFormData.dataProvider as ArrayCollection )
                if( !targetProvider ){
                    targetProvider = new ArrayCollection()
                }
                targetProvider.addItem(( e.currentTarget as DataGrid).selectedItem )
                bdgFormData.dataProvider = targetProvider
            }

    ]]> 
</mx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid id="myStaticDataGrid" click="onSelect(event)" >
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:ArrayCollection >
            <mx:Object label="AIR" />
            <mx:Object label="ColdFusion" />
            <mx:Object label="Dreamweaver" />
            <mx:Object label="Flash" />
            <mx:Object label="Flex" />
            <mx:Object label="Photoshop" />
        </mx:ArrayCollection>
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:DataGrid id="bdgFormData" x="240" y="0"/>
```